# Ramdisk ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ramdisk

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04(64bit) for my desktop.
The machine has a 5GB RAM.

I want to use RAM disk(1G or 2G) but I don't know how can I do this.

Is there any opensource product of RAM disk?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The technology is built into the kernel, you don't need any extra tools. In fact, you already have a few RAM disks (which you shouldn't use, they're reserved for the system), which you can see by doing

```
grep -w tmpfs /proc/mounts
```

To set up a 2GB RAM disk mounted on `/ramdisk`, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
ramdisk  /ramdisk  tmpfs  mode=1777,size=2g
```

Then mount the disk with the command `mount /ramdisk` (this will be done automatically when you reboot).

The indicated size is a maximum, the disk only uses as much memory as the files that are on it.

---

You can change `/tmp` to be a RAM disk. In the `/etc/fstab` line above, put `/tmp` rather than `/ramdisk`, then reboot.

The first time you reboot after changing `/tmp` to be a RAM disk, the files that were in `/tmp` will be hidden. That's harmless, except that they're wasting a little disk space. You can clean them up (*after* you've rebooted with `/tmp` on the RAM disk) by doing

```
mount --bind / /mnt
rm -r /mnt/tmp/* /mnt/tmp/.*
umount /mnt
```

The `mount --bind` command makes `/mnt` a duplicate view of your root filesystem; but while the RAM disk now obscures `/tmp` on the root view, nothing is obscuring `/mnt/tmp`.

**ADDED**: You can switch `/tmp` to a RAM disk without rebooting, it's just a little more complicated. Add the line to `/etc/fstab` as above, then run the following commands:

```
mkdir /tmp.old
mount --bind /tmp /tmp.old
mount /tmp
cd /tmp
ln -s /tmp.old/* /tmp/.* .
```

Then delete `/tmp.old` after your next reboot.

The reason you can't just move files from `/tmp.old` to `/tmp` is that some critical programs have files open in `/tmp`, for example `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` which the X server listens on and every GUI program opens when it starts. Moving a file to a different filesystem means copying it and deleting the old one, so you would end up with the X server still listening on `/tmp.old/.X11-unix/X0` but X clients contacting `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` in vain. On a server, you might get away with a move if you're careful.

Comment: @giles: Is there a way to do this without change to fstab and  rebooting? I'm assuming there's a corresponding mkfs method, followed by a mount but "man mkfs" wasn't very helpful.

Comment: @hotei: The reboot is only to switch `/tmp` over to `tmpfs`. It's not necessary, and I've edited my answer to explain how to do it, but it's more complicated. There's no `mkfs` involved because there's no underlying storage to prepare, the kernel handles everything.

Comment: @giles: Thanks for update.  I was missing the part where "magic happens" during mount's reading of the the fstab line.  I believe I understand why it works now.

Comment: Can I ask if this results in a noticeable speedup?

Comment: @Robert: I think it did cause a noticeable speed up on my netbook's very slow SSD (mainly because syncs can last several seconds and `/tmp` on the disk increases the frequency of syncs), but this is an unreliable subjective impression. I've never tried to benchmark.